# could not read column value from result set in Hibernate Native Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
 SELECT
  CONCAT(CREG.FIRSTNAME, ' ', CREG.LASTNAME) AS NAME,
  CASE WHEN CR.CAMPAIGNTYPE = 'NPS'
    THEN NPSSCORE
  ELSE CSATSCORE END                         AS SCORE,
  IFNULL(cast(CC.TEXT AS CHAR(255)), '')     AS COMMENTS,
  CREG.ID                                    AS CLIENTID,
  CR.ID                                      AS CAMPAIGNRESPONSEID,
  CI.ID                                      AS ISSUEID
FROM CUSTOMER_ISSUES CI INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ISSUEID
                                    FROM ISSUE_DEPARTMENT_MAPPING
                                    WHERE CUSTOMERUSERID = 91 AND ISSUE_STATUS = 'New') IDM
    ON CAST(CI.FEEDBACK_DATE AS DATE) BETWEEN '2016-06-05' AND '2016-06-11' AND IDM.ISSUEID = CI.ID
  INNER JOIN CAMPAIGN_RESPONSE CR ON CR.ID = CI.CAMPAIGN_RESPONSE_ID
  INNER JOIN CLIENT_REGISTRATION CREG ON CREG.ID = CR.RESPONSECUSTOMERID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CAMPAIGN_COMMENTS CC ON CC.CAMPAIGN_RESPONSE_ID = CR.ID;
```

The above query is running in the mysql-console properly ,but when I am integrating with the Hibernate,following error is thrown by Hibernate.

[BigIntegerType] could not read column value from result set: ID; Column 'ID' not found.

Comment: set `show_sql=true` get the SQL printed on log/console, check whether it runs fine in mysql-console. how are you binding parameters? also post complete stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the alias names in your SQL query.

Basically what happens here is when you run

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CREG.FIRSTNAME, ' ', CREG.LASTNAME) AS NAME,
  CASE WHEN CR.CAMPAIGNTYPE = 'NPS'
    THEN NPSSCORE
  ELSE CSATSCORE END                         AS SCORE,
  IFNULL(cast(CC.TEXT AS CHAR(255)), '')     AS COMMENTS,
  CREG.ID                                    AS CLIENTID,
  CR.ID                                      AS CAMPAIGNRESPONSEID,
  CI.ID                                      AS ISSUEID
```

in JDBC it returns the column as CREG.ID  instead of ClientID.
So try running the query without the aliases, typically, there is a problem in JDBC with this. If you still insist on using aliases,add the following entry to JDBC URL in configuration file

[useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true]

Comment: After removing the alias from all the id columns ,it worked!